# Can we put condition in ChrootDirectory directive of Match Group in SFTP configuration?

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

I am using SFTP with active directory. After authenticating users I am redirecting all users to one directory that is `upload2`. But now I want redirect some users to one directory and some users to another directory using ChrootDirectory directive. As per my knowledge in ChrootDirectory we can use only `%h` and `%u` parameters. Can we put condition in ChrootDirectory directive or more parameters?

```
AllowGroups     *
UsePAM yes

Subsystem      sftp     internal-sftp

Match Group sftp-users
        ChrootDirectory /upload2
        AllowTcpForwarding no
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use condition in `ChrootDirectory` directive. But the `Match` directive allows conditions, that's what it is for.

Put some users to one group, while other users to another group. And introduce a rule for each group with a different folder:

```
Match Group sftp-users1
    ChrootDirectory /upload1

Match Group sftp-users2
    ChrootDirectory /upload2
```

Or, if that's not possible, explicitly list users in each rule:

```
Match User user1,user2,user3
    ChrootDirectory /upload1

Match User user4,user5,user6
    ChrootDirectory /upload2
```